# How to use autoload together with namespace in php?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, autoloader

I want to use the __autoload function..
For example I have two files in the same folder:

index.php, MyClass.php

MyClass.php is something like this:

```
// filename: MyClass.php
namespace SomeNameSpace;

class MyClass{
    public static function helloWorld(){ echo 'Hello'; }
}
```

So what I want to do is to use __autoload to load this class. But when I do this:

```
function __autoload($className){
    include($className.'.php');
}
```

autoload does not work, because the class is in namespace.

Any help?

example for index.php:

```
//index.php
//the autoload method above
SomeNameSpace\MyClass::helloWorld();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are doing

```
include('$className'.'.php');
```

you are in fact looking for a file called "$classname.php". remove the single quotes.

Try:

```
function __autoload($className){
    include( end(explode('\\', $className)) . '.php');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is a mistake I made asking the question. The code is correct. It still does not work.

Comment: what do you get in $className ?

Comment: It tried to include SomeNameSpace\MyClass.php but MyClass.php is not in SomeNameSpace folder, it is in the same folder. So this is the problem.

Comment: I used DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR instead of '\\'. Thanks.